# Adding class to form element via hook_form_alter for views exposed filter is not working

Tags: 7, forms, views

I have a Views exposed filter, for which I am trying to add a class via `hook_form_alter()` with the following code:

```
$form['price']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('price-hide'));
```

Outputting the form array with devel shows that this is adding the attribute fine; however I can only assume there is another `hook_form_alter()` running after my module that is wiping my attributes, as other attributes are being added, and mine never make it to the HTML output.

I've tried moving from `hook_form_alter()` to `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter()` since I remember that hook running at a different time than `hook_form_alter()`; however, this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the actual markup after the page is rendered with Firebug or something to see for sure if another module's hook_form_alter() is overriding yours? If that is indeed the case then an easy way to get around is it by increasing your module's weight so hook_form_alter() in your module is called after other modules.

```
db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = 20 WHERE name = 'my_module'");
```

EDIT: I should say that this code should go in `hook_install()` and you should then reinstall your module to get the weight set properly.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the problem. I'm only using what you might call "middle of the road" modules, which I was hoping would play safe with overriding #attributes and not redeclare. Thanks I'll try this.